# How to pass DomSanitizer as an argument in typescript to a pipe?

Tags: angular, angular-pipe, angular-dom-sanitizer

I am using a pipe to display [feathericons](https://feathericons.com/) which has the following code :

```
import {DomSanitizer} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {Pipe, PipeTransform} from '@angular/core';

import { icons } from 'feather-icons'; // v4+

@Pipe({ name: 'feather' })
export class FeatherIconsPipe implements PipeTransform {

  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}

  transform(icon: string, size: number = 18, color: string = 'inherit', float: string = 'inline-end') {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(icons[icon].toSvg({
      width: size,
      height: size,
      color: color,
      float: float
    }));
  }
}
```

As you can see, it uses a DomSanitizer. I use the pipe in HTML like this :

```
 <span [innerHTML]="'home' | feather"></span>
```

It works fine. But now I need to do the same via typescript. I tried :

```
const span = this._renderer2.createElement('span');
let name = new FeatherIconsPipe().transform('home');
this._renderer2.setProperty(span, 'innerHTML', name);
```

But it throws error :

> Expected 1 arguments, but got 0.ts(2554)
>   feather-pipe.ts(9, 15): An argument for 'sanitizer' was not provided.

Then I tried

```
private sanitizer : DomSanitizer = this.sanitizer;
...
let name = new FeatherIconsPipe(this.sanitizer).transform('home');
```

But the pipe outputs :

> Cannot read property 'bypassSecurityTrustHtml' of undefined.

How can i set the innerHTML with pipe using typescript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Need to inject `sanitizer` to the constructor in your component

```
  constructor(private _renderer2: Renderer2, private sanitizer: DomSanitizer){

     new FeatherIconsPipe(this.sanitizer).transform('home');
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ne4fxk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: if you are using the render, u don't need to use the sanitizer the render the html  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ne4fxk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: the FeatherIconsPipe needs the sanitizer.

Comment: It did the trick but now I am getting output like "SafeValue must use [property]=binding:  [ home icon displays here] (see http://g.co/ng/security#xss)".

Using [property]=binding is not an option here, because I just created the element in typescript using renderer2. Can you help here?

Comment: why not use the demo i mentioned in the comments

Comment: That demo is not showing how to use my pipe which needs sanitizer. Anyways It is solved with your solution, thank you.

Comment: for the error "SafeValue must use [property]=binding: [ home icon displays here] (see g.co/ng/security#xss)"
 I did this "this._renderer2.setProperty(span, 'innerHTML', this.sanitizer.sanitize(SecurityContext.HTML,name));"